# code in visual studio not entering correct output, exits with a random number

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to visual studio and I cant seem to figure out what's wrong with the code. So I'll give an example if I write something like print("Hello World") it won't print what it says instead it would give a random number. This is what I just put:

```
print("hello world")
```

This is what I receive in the output

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/deep/vscode folder/app.py"
5

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.264 seconds
```

Forgive me for this simple question but I've tried looking on the web, I haven't found anything
[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: It says Unverified breakpoint. File is modified, please restart debug session,  what should I do?

Comment: You need to save the modifications, if you look at the tab at the top, right next to the file name, there is a circle, this means that the file has unsaved changes. After saving it, you can try re-running the application.

Comment: oh my god, I apologize for this basic question. lol, I was using pycharm before this so it's a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture, you can see that in the tab of your **app.py** file, there is a white dot. It means that the file is not saved. So, it is running the **previous code**. To save the file, press `Ctrl` `S`. To **auto save**, Go to `Settings` and search `Auto Save`.
Then select your preference on when to auto save.

Comment: I’m so sorry for this basic question, I was using pycharm before this so it’s all a little confusing. Thank you

Comment: it's ok. Sometimes I forget to save and then cry